# How to check existence of an input argument for R functions

Tags: r, function, arguments, exists

I have a function defined as

```
myFun <- function(x, y, ...) {
  # using exists
  if (exists("z")) { print("exists z!") }
  # using missing
  try(if (!missing("z")) { print("z is not missing!") }, silent = TRUE)
  # using get
  try(if (get("z")) { print("get z!") }, silent = TRUE)

  # anotherFun(...)
}
```

In this function, I want to check whether user input "z" in the argument list. How can I do that? I tried `exists("z")`, `missing("z")`, and `get("z")` and none of them works.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you've used `missing`? Because AFAIK that's the correct function to use.

Comment: It would help if you provide a bit more context.  There may be a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @joran, `missing()` only applies for argument. Here there is no argument `z`, it can only be entered as part of `...`

Comment: @SachaEpskamp I agree. I simply wasn't sure if what the OP wrote was actually what they were doing.

Comment: I've modified the code in the question to make it easier to understand. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

@Sacha Epskamp has a pretty good solution, but it doesn't always work. The case where it fails is if the "z" argument is passed in as NULL...

```
# Sacha's solution
myFun <- function(x, y, ...) { 
  args <- list(...)
  exist <- !is.null(args[['z']])
  return(exist)
}

myFun(x=3, z=NULL) # FALSE, but should be TRUE!


# My variant
myFun2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
  args <- list(...)
  exist <- "z" %in% names(args)
  exist
}

myFun2(x=3, z=NULL) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 83):

I think you're simply looking for `hasArg`

```
myFun <- function(x, y, ...) { 
  hasArg(z)
}

> myFun(x=3, z=NULL)
[1] TRUE
```

From `?hasArg`:

> The expression hasArg(x), for example, is similar to !missing(x), with
>   two exceptions. First, hasArg will look for an argument named x in the
>   call if x is not a formal argument to the calling function, but ...
>   is. Second, hasArg never generates an error if given a name as an
>   argument, whereas missing(x) generates an error if x is not a formal
>   argument.

Answer (score 10):

There might be instances when you might not want to call `list(...)`, since this will evaluate all the expressions in the dots. For example,

```
myFun <- function(x, y, ...){
  myArgs <- list(...)
  zInArgs <- ("z" %in% names(myArgs))
  return(zInArgs)
}

myFun(x = 2, y = "Happy", z = list(rep(rnorm(2e6), 100)))
```

This will take a long time. Instead, use `match.call()`:

```
myFun <- function(x, y, ...){
  myArgs <- match.call()
  zInArgs <- ("z" %in% names(myArgs))
  return(zInArgs)
}

myFun(x = 2, y = "Happy", z = list(rep(rnorm(2e6), 100)))
```

The first example is still chugging away on my machine, while the second example should take practically no time at all.

**EDIT:**

To answer the comment from @CarlWitthoft:

```
R> system.time(
+   (myAns <- myFun(x = 2, y = "Happy", z = list(rep(rnorm(2e6), 100))))
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
R> myAns
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: For completeness' sake, can you report on the time it *does* take to run the second example?

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthoft, please see my edit above. Do you get differing results?

Comment: well,  I get NULL for a result because I'm not allowed (yet) to install R at work :-(.   So, thanks for doing the timing tests.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way I often do it. First convert `...` to a list, then check if the elements are not `NULL`:

```
myFun <- function(x, y, ...) { 
args <- list(...)
exist <- !is.null(args[['z']])
return(exist)
}
```

Some results:

```
> myFun()
[1] FALSE
> myFun(z=1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I don't think this is the intended way `...` is supposed to be used though. It is more a way of passing arguments to another function, but this is how I currently use it in my package as well (I really should change that:))

Comment: Sacha, I do agree with you. If "z" is used in this function, it should  not be in the ...  But very often code is already written and making one change in the argument list can introduce errors that requires many changes to fix. So this is my lazy way to make it work. :)

Comment: I added an alternative solution that also handles `myFun(z=NULL)`

Comment: @danioyuan Also this gives you awesome hidden and undocumented arguments that only you know about!

Comment: @danioyuan: the safe, and possibly "proper," way to add an argument is to place it last in the list with a default value assigned, i.e. `myfunc(x,y,...)` becomes `myfunc(x,y,z=1,...)` . AFAIK that will provide full back-compatibility.