# How to check existence of an input argument for R functions without using '...'

Tags: r, function, arguments, user-defined

Please consider the following example to check for my arguments:

```
fun <- function(x, y, z) { 
  notexist <- is.null(y)
  return(notexist)
}

fun(x) # Should return TRUE since y is missing
fun(x,y) # Should return FALSE since y is being passed
```

I have come across a similar post which makes use of three-dots construct [How to check existence of an input argument for R functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877271/how-to-check-existence-of-an-input-argument-for-r-function). But I do not want to use exists, missing, get, hasArg and three-dots construct. But instead I want to write this code by just using the args and is.null()? Is it possible without three-dots?

Comment: Try `function(data, var1=NULL, var2=NULL)`

Comment: Worked its magic! Thanks.